# C++: How do I write a function that accepts an iterator and inserts elements?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

```
template<class Container>
void BlitSurface::ExtractFrames(Container & output, int frame_width, int frame_height,
                                         int frames_per_row, int frames_per_column,
                                         bool padding) const
{
    SDL_Surface ** temp_surf = SDL_Ex_ExtractFrames(_surface, frame_width, frame_height, frames_per_row, frames_per_column, padding);

    int surface_count = frames_per_row * frames_per_column;

    output.resize(surface_count);
    Container::iterator iter = output.begin();

    for(int i=0; i<surface_count; ++i, ++iter)
        iter->_surface = temp_surf[i];

    delete [] temp_surf;
}
```

I have this function splits an image up into frames and stores them into a container of images.  How would I modify it to take an iterator instead of a container, and insert the elements at that point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `back_inserter`:

```
template<typename OutputIterator>
void BlitSurface::ExtractFrames(OutputIterator it, int frame_width, int frame_height,
                                         int frames_per_row, int frames_per_column,
                                         bool padding) const
{
    /* ... other lines unchanged ...*/
    for(int i=0; i<surface_count; ++i) {
        // "BlitSurface()" sets other members to zero. Alternatively you
        // can use boost::value_initialized for that. 
        BlitSurface bs = BlitSurface();
        bs._surface = temp_surf[i];
        *it++ = bs;
    }
    delete [] temp_surf;
}
```

Then call it like

```
ExtractFrames(std::back_inserter(container), ...);
```

Comment: Every time I see an answer like this I learn how little I know about STL. :(

Comment: I did this: ExtractFrames(std::back_inserter(surface_vec), c_width, c_height, 16, 6, true);  -------- And then I get the following errors: "error C2182: 'v' : illegal use of type 'void'", "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'value_type' to 'int'", and some others.  surface_vec is an std::vector<BlitSurface>

Comment: @user um my bad. output-iterators don't expose value_type :(

Comment: @Johannes: I do wonder why, do you happen to know the reason ?

Comment: @Matthieu, i've no idea. But maybe so they could support "polymorphic" iterators. A stream-output iterator could be created like `output_iterator(cout)` and one could then do `*it++ = "value:"; *it++ = 42;`.